# PyCharm shows "PEP8: expected 2 blank lines, found 1"

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, pep8

Consider the following code:

```
def add_function(a, b):
    c = str(a) + b
    print "c is %s" % c

def add_int_function(c, d):
    e = c + d
    print "the vaule of e is %d" % e

if __name__ =="__main__":
    add_function(59906, 'kugrt5')
    add_int_function(1, 2)
```

It always shows me: "expected 2 blank lines ，found 1" in a`add_int_function`, but not in the `add_function`.

When I add two spaces in front of the `def add_int_function(c, d):`
there is a error shows `unindent does not match any outer indentation level`
in the end of `add_function`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you find and answer useful, accept that answer by clicking on its check-mark (like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png))so that other people will know the answer worked for you in the first look

Comment: PyCharm will fix it for you if you click on the code or press **Alt-Enter** and then click the yellow lightbulb and select **Reformat file**

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Just add another line between your function definitions :

1 line :

[image]

2 lines:

[image]

Comment: @march_seven if this solved your issue you can accept the answer so that the others will immediately find out this solved the problem

Comment: Why is this necessary? What happens if there is just 1 line between the functions?

Comment: @FranzDeschler nothing happens, it just does not conform to the style guide, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines

Comment: Is it possible to turn this pep8 behaviour off?

Comment: @Leo Ufimtsev Go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> PEP 8 coding style violation. Then press the check mark to disable it. You can also change the severity if you want to.

Comment: @grandBagel Some things are better left unknown

Answer (score 9):

This is a pretty common question within the python community. After the release of PEP 8, new formatting styles were accepted into python. One of them states that after the definition of a class or function there must be two lines separating them. As such:

```
    def yadayada:
     print("two lines between the functions")


    def secondyadayada:
     print("this is the proper formatting")
```

So, you should never do it like:

```
    def yadayada:
     print("two lines between the functions")

    def secondyadayada:
     print("this is the proper formatting")
```

Or else PyCharm will throw that error at you.

Answer (score 2):

For people who wonders why it requires two blank lines

if you were to write in other languages it would be:

```
fun doSth() {
    print()
}

fun doSth1() {
    print()
}
```

but if you were to delete all the curly braces from the code you will see:

two blank lines between methods

```
fun doSth()
    print()
#
#
fun doSth1()
    print()
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Further clarification on @kennet-celeste & @shreyshrey 's answers,

Each function or class defined requires 2 spaces above and 2 spaces below. Unless the function is the last item in the script, in which the expected format is one blank line as an End of File marker. So:

```
# some code followed by 2 blank spaces


def function1():


def function2():


def function3():
```